# How to modify style of excel report retrieved from SSRS as bytes?

Tags: .net, excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, memorystream

I need to modify some style in SSRS report after I retrieve it from server. (This may be useful: When I retrieve the report in format EXCEL and return it to user as file, extension of the file is xls.)

At first I get byte[], which I tried to convert to SpreadsheetDocument, but it returns error Corrupt data. What is the problem? How can I achieve this?

```
//code snippet
ssrsHelper.ExecuteReport( model, "EXCEL" );
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(model.ReportBits);
OpenAndAddToSpreadsheetStream( memStream );
model.ReportBits = memStream.ToArray();

public void OpenAndAddToSpreadsheetStream( Stream stream )
{
    // Open a SpreadsheetDocument based on a stream.
    SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open( stream, true );

    //change style somehow

    // Close the document handle.
    spreadsheetDocument.Close();
}
```